# Head node of Linked List

Tags: java, linked-list

So I was wondering how I could create a new empty linked list, using my class definition of List and node, with a first head node pointing to null without having to hold any integer value. The thing is I'm not allowed to change the given methods or add any to the definition, so whenever I create a list, in the constructor I'm not sure how I'm supposed to asign head to null. Here's part of the codes:

```
public class Node {
   private Node next;
   private int key;

   Node(Node nxt, int keyValue) {
      key = keyValue;
      next = nxt;      
   }
   Node getNext() {
      return next;
   }   
   int getKey() {
      return key;
   }
   void putNext(Node nxt) {
      next = nxt;
   }   
}
```

Class List

```
public class List {
    private Node head;
    List() {
       head = new Node(null, -1); // arbitary value for head 
       head.putNext(null); 
    }
```

This is what I came up with. I just assign a random value to variable key in head node. But if I do this, it will kinda mess up with my later methods that used recursive like deletion or finding sum or find max, min, etc
Is there any other way around I can do to deal with this issue?

Comment: Take a look at the implementation of `java.util.LinkedList` for some ideas. There should be a lot of similarities between what you're doing for your class assignment and how this class works.

Comment: Can you not just use `head = null`? Heck, that's the default value for `head` anyway... (You don't *have* to - you certainly *can* use a sentinel value for the head of the list, but I'm not sure I'd bother in this case.)

Comment: @jon is right! `head = null;` is the perfect thing to place in your constructor. also your call `head.putNext(null);` in your constructor is superfluous since your constructor sets `next` to `null`, you will be doing the same thing twice!

Comment: Chris: in the constructor, it doesnt specify how it creates an empty list so I still cant figure out how.

Comment: yeah thanks guys head = null should be working for now. That is i need to change all my codes according to that. I'll try work that out and see if anything else comes up

Comment: Note that as I said before, you don't actually need to even make the assignment explicit - `null` is the default value.

Comment: Thanks again. I fixed all the bugs. They're all working fine now :)

Answer (score 0):

In an Empty Linked List Head is Just a pointer which points to Nothing. You dont need to worry about creating an object to which current head points. Just create a head pointer and assign it to NULL. When you are actually adding a Node assign the address of first node to Head. Thats it...

```
public class List {
    private Node *head;
    List() {
       head = NULL; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that a C++ snippet? The author talked about Java